# Vue: removing event listener on destroy

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue directed I use in order to apply a fixed class to the inserted DOM element, in order to do this I also attach an event listener to the window object to run when the user scrolls.

My question is, should I remove this event listener when my element is destroyed? I heard the scroll event can affect performance and I'm not sure if the event listener is automatically destroyed each time I refresh a page (my app is not SPA but a laravel app with vue for frontend).

This is my directive:

```
Vue.directive('scroll-apply-class', {
    isLiteral: true,
    inserted: (el, binding, vnode) => {

        let scrolled = false;
        let stickyTop = 300;

        setTimeout(function(){

            stickyTop = el.offsetTop;

            checkPosition();

            window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
                scrolled = true;
            });

        }, 2500);


        let checkPosition = function(){
            if (window.pageYOffset > stickyTop && window.innerWidth > 765) {
                el.classList.add(binding.value)
            }
            else {
                el.classList.remove(binding.value)
            }   
        };


        let timeout = setInterval(function() {
            if (scrolled) {
                scrolled = false;
                checkPosition();
            }
        }, 2500);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about "decency" then yes, do the right thing, remove that listener. But from a pragmatist's view, maybe not. Since your app is not SPA, each time user click a link and go to other page, that problem is automatically taken cared.

But still, it depends. Is there any chance that in some scenario, this directive is loaded many times on one long-lasting visit to one of your pages? If there is such case, then it's a good idea to properly unregister the listener. If no, the directive is only loaded once, then you can safely leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the event listeners on the window in the `unbind` hook. However, in order to remove the event listeners, you will need to store their callbacks. This can be done by simply storing it as a property of `el`, e.g. `el.scrollCallback`:

```
bind: (el) => {
    el.scrollCallback = () => {
        el.dataset.scrolled = true;
    }
},
unbind: (el) => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', el.scrollCallback);
},
```

Then, in your `inserted` hook, just update the way you store the `scrolled` boolean. Instead of encapsulating it within the hook, you can store it in the `el`'s dataset so that it can be accessed by other hooks:

```
inserted: (el, binding, vnode) => {

    // Store data in element directly
    el.dataset.scrolled = false;

    let stickyTop = 300;

    setTimeout(function(){

        stickyTop = el.offsetTop;

        checkPosition();

        window.addEventListener('scroll', el.scrollCallback);

    }, 2500);

    // REST OF YOUR CODE HERE

    // Remember to update all references to `scrolled` to `el.dataset.scrolled`
    let timeout = setInterval(function() {
        if (el.dataset.scrolled) {
            el.dataset.scrolled = false;
            checkPosition();
        }
    }, 2500);

}
```